How can I integrate spell checking into my Visual Studio Solution, as part of Visual Studio Pro, and Pipeline usage?
I'm having a tough time finding a solution to what seems to be a definite problem that's been solved. My team has an extensive VS solution that we want to add spell-checking too. Specifically, we'd like for Visual Studio to mark misspellings in code as warnings, but misspellings in string literals as errors.  This also needs to halt the local build process In VS for a worker, and it also needs to be integrated into our build pipeline.
I have found multiple spell checking tools however, they all seem to fall-short and do not provide all of these features.  Some tools seem to integrate with VS Code, which is not what we're developing in, while others like WeCantSpell.Rosyln are either half-baked or not well documented.
What I need to be able to do is this:

Analyze and check spelling, dynamically and automatically within Visual Studio Professional.
Have a way to manage the dictionary and/or provide an "Ignore Words" list
Integrate the exact same tool into the build process so that errors are consistent across Visual Studio and the build pipeline.

What am I missing? What tool can both provide a build process and a VS Analyzer setup?
